# Export Data inside the folder

Tags: android, export-to-excel

I am using following code for export data.

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    File sd = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    String csvFile = "expensesData.xls";
    File directory = new File(sd.getAbsolutePath());
    //create directory if not exist
    if (!directory.isDirectory()) {
        directory.mkdirs();
    }
    try {

        //file path
        File file = new File(directory, csvFile);
        WorkbookSettings wbSettings = new WorkbookSettings();
        WritableWorkbook workbook;
        workbook = Workbook.createWorkbook(file, wbSettings);
        //Excel sheet name. 0 represents first sheet
        WritableSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("userList", 0);
        // column and row
        sheet.addCell(new Label(0, 0, "Type"));
        sheet.addCell(new Label(1, 0, "Amount"));
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT expenses_type,amount" +
                "FROM expenses_diary", null);
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                String ex_type = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("expenses_type"));
                String ex_amount = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("amount"));
                int i = cursor.getPosition() + 1;
                sheet.addCell(new Label(0, i, ex_type));
                sheet.addCell(new Label(1, i, ex_amount));
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        cursor.close();
        workbook.write();
        workbook.close();
        showToast("Exporting...");
        showToast("Data Exported - expensesData.xls");
    } catch (WriteException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
   }
});
```

the exported file is storing in Root of Internal Storage, but I want to store that file inside the folder.(For example,currently in `/expensesData.xls`,but I want `ExpensesApp/expensesData.xls`.

I think this is simple,but am new in android, so I don't know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First create a object of the file class for the directory you wish to create

```
File folder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/ExpensesApp/");
```

Check if folder exists and create it if it doesn't exist

```
if (!folder.exists())
   folder.mkdir();
```

Then create your xls file

```
File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/ExpensesApp/expensesData.xls");
```

Comment: Thank you @Anuraag Baishya. Can only export into internal stoarage.?

Comment: Can export into secondary storage i.e.sd card.?

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47111244/cant-access-the-secondary-storage-the-external-removable-micro-sd-card

Comment: `File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/ExpensesApp/expensesData.xls");` Oh Oh O ... not again! `File file = new File(folder, "expensesData.xls");`.

Comment: `if (!folder.exists())
   folder.mkdir();` Check the return value as it might fail. `if (!folder.exists())
   if ( !folder.mkdir()) return;`.