# Android delete file on SD on Androud api 4.4.+

Tags: android

I have a `File` object, `file`. This `file` points to a file on the SD card. How can I delete this `file` on Android api version 5.+ ? I have `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />` permission in Manifest also called in in run time. I have tried `file.delete()` it works for internal and external storage but file is not deleted on **SD Card/Secondary storage**. Any suggestions?

Comment: If you have the `File` object and the read/write permission for external storage, you can just call `file.delete()`. That being said, try reading documentation on the class you are working with before posting it as a question

Comment: @osman have a look on this answer. this may help you [click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1248292/how-to-delete-a-file-from-sd-card)

Comment: `file.delete()` not working for files on SD card. According to what I found google restricted SD card write access after api version 4.4

Answer (score 0):

You can delete any file or dir by this method:

```
File f = new File("your path");
f.delete();
```

and don't forget to add permission in menifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

and above version 6.0 you need to give runtime permission like this:

```
final String[] NECESSARY_PERMISSIONS = new String[] {Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE};

    if ((ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(),
            Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)) {
    {
            //Permission granted.
    }
    else
    {       
            // Request for permission
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getApplicationContext(),
                    NECESSARY_PERMISSIONS, 123);
    }
```

Comment: I have permission. `file.delete()` not working on SD card. I have already tried this.

Comment: you are run on 6.0 > version ?

Comment: I am developing on android Lollipop. I have considered run time permission. I can see the app has the WRITE permission in the app Settings. **Please note, I can delete the same file on internal and external storage. However, file is not deleted on SD CARD/Secondary Storage**

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47111244/cant-access-the-secondary-storage-the-external-removable-micro-sd-card

Answer (score 0):

@osman may be your not implementing run time permissions concept

Comment: Yes I have considered run time `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission. **Please note, I can delete the same file on internal and external storage. However, file is not deleted on SD CARD/Secondary Storage**

Comment: @osman have a look on this  link  https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/96500/how-to-allow-apps-to-delete-sd-card-content

Comment: I have already saw this question. The only feasible option seems to be the ' systems storage provider'. But couldn't find any working example.